# Save a dataframe with special characters as a csv

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, csv

I have this dataframe:

data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['text,\ttabwith,co"mma";', 'text;with;"semi"c|olons', 'text\tw\ith\ttab'], 'col3': ['text,\ttabwith,comma;', 'text;wit|h;semicolons', 9]}

And I want to save it as a csv but when working with .to_csv() it gets the columns and rows mixed, I have tried with open('.csv') and other functions but I am not able to keep the dataframe as it is when exporting it. Any ideas on what can I do?

I expect to get a dataframe like the one in python:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr3sD.png)

And I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8euHl.png)

Comment: Looks like this is a problem on how you load your file in Excel. You can check what your file looks like in a normal text editor to make sure. Try to adjust the import settings in Excel, so that it expects a csv, not a tsv for instance

Comment: You might also add a quoting parameter to your to_csv() call. Maybe `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem on the tabulation of excel, not python. Use `.to_csv(sep=';')` since `;` is the default separator for excel.

Comment: In my experience, CSV support / import / open in Excel is a quite mixed bag that changes behaviour depending on the system locale. I wish Excel had some way of configuring how to import a CSV (and ability to set "use defaults X,Y,Z  OR ask me each time). I guess Microsoft trying to be "friendly" and hide scary technology.